# SSH key not working with a different name

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

When I'm trying to log in to a server using a public key for a ssh connection with a different name (other than `id_rsa.pub`, which is default name, I guess), it is not working and keeps asking for the server password. I copied the ssh public key to the remote server, but it keeps asking for a user password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command for copy the ssh `id_rsa.pub` file from source to remote server and also you need to change the permission to 600 for `authorized_keys`

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@serverhostname
```